# Running User Database on EC2 but domain is hosted elsewhere

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have a user database and some PHP scripts running on an EC2 instance. However my domain and site are in another location (on shopify). The EC2 instance is running as a subdomain A record.

I am wondering how I can combine the two so that requests from my site are processed on the EC2 instance as if they were on the same server. Is that possible? Is it a practice that people usually employ when using EC2 for processing?

Answer (score 0):

In technical terms, a web site is generally one or more servers that respond to requests for a given set of addresses as defined by one or more A records.

What this means is if you want your PHP site on EC2 to be the primary service, you'll have to point your domain and associated host names to that directly. To still make use of Shopify, you'll have to proxy requests from your site to that somehow, or set up Shopify to use a subdomain, in effect flipping the configuration you have now.

It's not clear what you're trying to do without specific examples.